# uniapp development native plugin, some models have flashback: dyld4::APIs::_dyld_missing_symbol_abort

Tags: ios, c

Details, I wrote a payment plug-in in the IOS project, using a static library structure, the local run no problem, after the online part of the user feedback APP flashback, check the feedback log as follows

```
Incident Identifier: 0D28CF0B-403B-4F51-9CA9-055D09BB6451
Hardware Model:      iPhone14,5
Process:             平头哥口语 [38306]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F390352E-63DE-4109-9A86-BB9DA301D279/平头哥口语.app/平头哥口语
Identifier:          ptg.eaglemobi.release
Version:             2.0.5 (200005)
AppStoreTools:       15E204
AppVariant:          1:iPhone14,5:15
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           ptg.eaglemobi.release [9109]

Date/Time:           2024-03-11 22:28:02.8447 +0800
Launch Time:         2024-03-11 22:28:02.5161 +0800
OS Version:          iPhone OS 15.6.1 (19G82)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    1.70.01
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0


Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   dyld                            0x0000000105468b14 __abort_with_payload + 8
1   dyld                            0x000000010546e6cc abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 104 (terminate_with_reason.c:102)
2   dyld                            0x000000010546e700 abort_with_payload + 16 (terminate_with_reason.c:124)
3   dyld                            0x000000010543ea00 dyld4::halt(char const*) + 580 (DyldProcessConfig.cpp:2102)
4   dyld                            0x000000010544fd84 dyld4::APIs::_dyld_missing_symbol_abort() + 44 (DyldAPIs.cpp:2488)
5   平头哥口语                           0x0000000104546440 -[TestModule initializingAndRegisteringListeners:callback:] + 44
6   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001dcfe1b24 __invoking___ + 148 (:-1)
7   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001dcfff610 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 468 (NSForwarding.m:3378)
8   平头哥口语                           0x00000001047b9ccc __53-[WXModuleMethod _dispatchInvocation:moduleInstance:]_block_invoke + 44 (WXModuleMethod.m:139)
9   Foundation                      0x00000001de7f5f00 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 212 (NSThread.m:1058)
10  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001dd07b414 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28 (CFRunLoop.c:1972)
11  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001dd08c1a0 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 208 (CFRunLoop.c:2016)
12  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001dcfc5694 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 268 (CFRunLoop.c:2053)
13  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001dcfcb05c __CFRunLoopRun + 828 (CFRunLoop.c:2951)
14  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001dcfdebc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3268)
15  GraphicsServices                0x00000001f914a374 GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2200)
16  UIKitCore                       0x00000001df952b58 -[UIApplication _run] + 1100 (UIApplication.m:3511)
17  UIKitCore                       0x00000001df6d4090 UIApplicationMain + 364 (UIApplication.m:5064)
18  平头哥口语                           0x0000000104544f30 main + 80 (main.m:16)
19  dyld                            0x0000000105439da4 start + 520 (dyldMain.cpp:879)
```

I can't get my head around this, I tried to use @try_@catch in the library file to catch the error, but it failed

Comment: According to the troubleshooting, the problem lies in the premature deprecation of static libraries, which in some models have not yet loaded the resources in the library, causing a crash, due to the delay in the call to the library of the code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.